# Site not loading when www is left out of the URL

Tags: iis, web-server, asp.net, website

Why does my website not load if I type:

> example.com

But it does work when I type:

> www.example.com

Is this a setting in IIS?

We are using ASP.NET 3.5 with a SQL Server database.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you have the DNS records for example.com and www.example.com pointing to the web server, you must still tell IIS7 which site to serve up when it sees these domains.

This is acheived through adding a "Binding" for each domain name (called a Host Header) to tell IIS which "site" to serve up to the client.

You will need a binding for "www.example.com" and a binding for "example.com".

See a picture here: http://www.iishacks.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/host-header-iis7.gif

Comment: You can see a text description here, too: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692%28WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What you need is having tool for URL rewrite to check if URL was put as *http://domain.com*, if so - add *www.* inside.
For this things you'll need additional software for redirect. 
Me myself was using ISAPI_Rewrite tool for simple things like rewrite, also this software can be provided free. Now I'm using Helicon Ape as an Apache emulator for IIS7.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you have to actually add a DNS record for example.com to your DNS in order for your site to be accessible at both example.com and www.example.com - if both of these records already exist in the DNS then it's probably an IIS setting somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Kenny's solution is probably the simplest. But if your web pages or application code depend on the url being www.example.com, they won't work properly.

A different solution is to set up a new site for example.com in IIS and use an http redirect to refer requests to www.example.com. Your users' sessions will continue on www.example.com, and all your site code will work as normal.

Answer (score 0):

In apache I would add www.example.com as an alias to example.com and done.
I suppose in IIS should be the same principle...